Nominations for new TNB Room Owners 2024
By community consensus, we've decided to elect new room owners for The Nineteenth Byte, CGCC's main chat room. The process will work as follows:

For one week (until UTC midnight on Monday 11th November), nominations will be accepted as answers on this meta post. You may nominate any user, including yourself, and if you are nominated by someone else, please indicate whether or not you accept the nomination as a comment under the nomination or via some reasonable method.
After the nominations period, an election will be held lasting one week. This will be on a separate meta post. Votes here have no impact, but feel free to vote how you want anyway.
Rather than having a fixed amount of slots, all users who receive 10 or more upvotes, and at least three times as many upvotes as downvotes, will be added as room owners, subject to approval by the current mods and ROs.

In each nomination, please include:

The user being nominated
Common active times in chat
A short blurb about why this user would be a good room owner

This post was drafted by rydwolf and modified by me back to the usual two-stage format with parts stolen from previous posts. Here's why I'm posting this and not rydwolf.

If you'd like a style guide for nominations, see the last three times we've done this.

Seggan
Greetings humans! My name is Seggan. As you can see I am mostly active during the Eastern (US) time zone:

Pros of me being an RO:

I have already experience ROing other rooms, most notably The Garbage Collector (the main chat room of our sister site PLDI), helping clean up messages and maybe even getting a few stars along the way.
I am relatively active in chat, keeping the chat tab pinned on my computer and making a conscious effort to read everything that has happened when I am not in chat. The password is vyxal limb stealing steggan fridge nuke.
I am sorta well entrenched here, having as of this moment 5417 reputation.
I haven't changed my username, like, ever, except for that one time as a joke.

Cons:

I am not too active on the main site these days, although that's partially because I've been working on a Chef transpi - I've said too much.
I cannot moderate on Sundays too much, as I have IRL things to attend to.


Ginger
hi! I'm Ginger. You probably know me from Vyxal, or PLDI (where I'm already an RO of its main chatroom), or one of the bots I maintain, or my regular presence in TNB (and TST before its unfortunate demise at the hands of Consensus). Here's when I'm active:

Effectively, daylight hours for the east coast of North America. I'm almost always watching discussion happening in the room, even if I'm not participating in it; as of right now I'm in the "frequently in room" list for TNB. Over my three-year tenure here, I believe I have absorbed reputation the rules and expectations of this site; I would be honored to be made an RO and contribute back to the community I so enjoy being a part of.

Redz
This is a nomination posted on behalf of Redz, who has expressed interest in ROing, but will most likely not be around to post a self-nomination.
Redz is one of the room owners over in The Garbage Collector on PLDI, and, in my opinion, be a great addition to the room owner list.
Activity Graph:

Pros [based on observations]:

She's quick to learn and adapt to room cultures, meaning she'd pretty quickly be able to get a good understanding of when things should be moved.
As aforementioned, Redz ROs the main room for PLDI, meaning that there's already RO experience.

Cons:

UTC+10-UTC+12 is already a fairly moderated timezone (emanresu being in UTC+11/12 and me [lyxal] being in UTC+10/11). I know Redz is also in UTC+10/11.


self nomination
chat activity 

Thought I might as well throw my hat in the ring.
Hi. You might know me for golfing Wolfram Language. I don't think much else I've done adjacent to CGCC is very notable so if you know me for something else that's slightly terrifying.
Pros:

I'm often lurking in chat, even if I don't type much.
Previous experience moderating (discord servers ~1-10 k users).
Reasonably active on CGCC.
My name has not changed in years.

Cons:

I often don't type much, even if I'm lurking in chat.
No experience with SE chat moderation.
Relatively short history of activity in TNB.
I've been thinking about changing my name for years.


Themoonisacheese
Hi there, you can call me themoon if that's preferable to you.
I'm a sysadmin and I currently help Ginger host the CGPC Gaming Satisfactory server, and I am temporarly giving a spare room to RubenVergs golf together
I'm active in chat monday-friday from 9 to 5 (CET):

Pros:

I'm basically always lurking during my work hours, it's like i'm being paid to be here.
I have moderate experience with moderation of public (2k+ users) discords.
EU timezone is currently not very moderated (though chat is well behaved).

Cons:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/66509730#66509730
I'm not very familiar with the tools available to moderate on chat.SE


New Posts
Active Times

Pros

Rarely causes drama
Has been active in the chat room for 4 years, so presumably has a good idea of room culture
Often helps in moderating of the main site by alerting us to problematic posts.
Loves Butter
Has the lyxal seal of approval (tm) (see below)



Seggan approves this message

Cons

Occasional onebox abuse

This is a joke

This has my full endorsement [edited into the nomination]

I wonder if this user will accept the nomination...

New Posts is a bot. I'm not speaking for the mod or RO team here, just for myself, but I don't see any reason to appoint a bot as RO and so I oppose this nomination, to be 100% clear (even if this is a joke)

The Empty String Photographer

As you can see, I am quite active during weekends.
Advantages of me being RO

Pretty active in the morning, when all those Americans are sleeping.
None of the other nominees are very active on Saturday and Sunday.
I have more than 2k rep on CGCC!
I am quite active on TNB.
I haven’t changed my username in quite a while.
I understand a decent amount of chat’s mechanics, like CHAT.addEventHandlerHook.
I am the creator of Utility Bot!

Cons
• I can be a little silly at times, although I always stop when I’m asked to.
